# How can I crawling on this page? I have a specific error

Tags: python

Question: I have the error (see in image below). I wanted to move on next page to
click button but code doesn't move on. How can I use this code?

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing the error. It might be because of a wrong xpath.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='next']").click()
```

It might be easier to find the "next" element using an id or class like this-

```
driver.find_element_by_id("#element_id")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div .... a.next")
```

Also, the full xpath is something like this. Maybe try this once

```
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/section[4]/div[2]/a[12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoking driver.execute seems to work due to overlapping element.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
for i in range(1, pageNum):
    elem=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='next']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
    time.sleep(1)
```